# Check if specific php script is running in windows ,by script name

Tags: php, windows, shell, exec

I am running PHP script form my API by running :

```
shell_exec('php . php-file.php');
```

then in refresh, I want to call API to check if the process is still running

I tried this:

```
exec(tasklist 2>NUL" , $task_list);
```

but in the task list, there is only php.exe

How can I get the specific file name or something else to know exactly if this is the script that still running;

Comment: You could use a database to keep track of the state of the PHP process you're running in the background. The PHP process should report its state to the database, regularly updating when it's still busy, and you can then read the status from within another PHP process by looking in the database. Similarly you could use any other means to store this information, like a file or any other thing you can manipulate on the computer, but a database is more commonly used.

Comment: I don't run PHP on windows. But I do have a suggestion for you. Open a cmd window on a windows machine, do a `tasklist.exe /?` and see if there's a parameter (eg. the last column in /V (verbose)?) that will give the extra info you need... 
But ehm, I'm sure there's another better solution to this programmatically. Like the one above described by @KIKO Software.